# Why use sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF) to get the number of CPU cores in x264?

Tags: android, c, multithreading, libc, x264

I find x264 use sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF) instead of sysconf(SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN) to get the number of CPU cores.

Here is the code snippet in [x264/common/cpu.c](https://github.com/mirror/x264/blob/master/common/cpu.c):

```
...
#ifdef __ANDROID__
    // Android NDK does not expose sched_getaffinity
    return sysconf( _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF );
#else
    ...
....
```

And I find the difference between _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF and _SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN in this [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Processor-Resources.html):

> sysconf (_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF) which returns the number of processors
>   the operating system configured. But it might be possible for the
>   operating system to disable individual processors and so the call
>   sysconf (_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN) returns the number of processors which
>   are currently online (i.e., available).

I have two questions:

1. What is the difference between "the number of processors the operating system configured" and "the number of processors which are currently online"?
2. Why x264 use _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF in Android to get the number of CPU cores?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you look at the source file you referenced, it uses neither of these on Linux (non-Android); it calls [`sched_getaffinity`(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_getaffinity) instead, on its own thread, and counts the number of 1 bits in the returned mask.

Linux systems can support “hot-pluggable” CPUs; this means the number of CPUs available can change over time, without a reboot. This might be a fault-tolerance measure in a high-availability cluster. Or it can also be a power-saving measure, e.g. in mobile or embedded devices. So x264 is clearly trying to make use of this capability where it is available, only falling back to less dynamic options where it has to.